# Draw an arrow that is always pointing away from an object

Tags: javascript, graphics, fabricjs

I have a canvas with a circle and a triangle with a line connecting them both. I'm attempting to use the triangle as an arrow. I'd like for the arrow to always point away from the center of the circle if either object is moved. I thought I could use the angle of the line to rotate the triangle but the results are unsatisfactory and I'm certain my approach is wrong.

Any suggestions or tips for solving this problem? In my linked JSFiddle you can move either object around and the angle of the triangle is rotated, but it's never quite right:

https://jsfiddle.net/zh1bkfs5/

```
const c = new fabric.Canvas('c');
c.preserveObjectStacking = true;

function radiansToDegrees (radians) {
  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function calcAngle (opposite, adjacent) {
  return radiansToDegrees(Math.atan(opposite / adjacent));
}

function syncObjects (e) {

  const x1 = triangle.left;
  const y1 = triangle.top;
  const x2 = circle.left + circle.radius;
  const y2 = circle.top + circle.radius;

  line.set('x1', x1);
  line.set('y1', y1);
  line.set('x2', x2);
  line.set('y2', y2);

  const angle = calcAngle(y2 - y1, x1 - x2);

  triangle.set('angle', -angle);
  triangle.setCoords();

  c.renderAll();
}

const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: 'black',
  radius: 20,
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false
});

const triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  fill: 'orange',
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  top: 50,
  left: 120,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

const coords = [
  triangle.left,
  triangle.top,
  circle.left + circle.radius,
  circle.top + circle.radius
];

const line = new fabric.Line(coords, {
  stroke: 'orange',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  selectable: false
});

c.add(circle, line, triangle);

c.on('object:moving', syncObjects);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the part of your syncObject function to this:

```
const x = x1 - x2;
const y = y2 - y1;
const angle = calcAngle(x, y);
if(x < 0 && y > 0 || x > 0 && y > 0) {
   triangle.set('angle', angle);
} else if(x < 0 && y < 0) {
   triangle.set('angle', 180 + angle);
} if(x > 0 && y < 0) {
   triangle.set('angle', -180 + angle);
}
```

this should work. Your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zh1bkfs5/30/

Comment: Ahhh, perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had my the values for "adjacent" and "opposite" flipped, after updating that I no longer needed to invert the angle. I'm now 99% there, just have a case where the triangle is sometimes flipped the wrong way but should be easy to fix at least my initial approach worked.

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/zh1bkfs5/1/

```
const c = new fabric.Canvas('c');
c.preserveObjectStacking = true;

function radiansToDegrees (radians) {
  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function calcAngle (opposite, adjacent) {
  return radiansToDegrees(Math.atan(opposite / adjacent));
}

function syncObjects (e) {

  const x1 = triangle.left;
  const y1 = triangle.top;
  const x2 = circle.left + circle.radius;
  const y2 = circle.top + circle.radius;

  line.set('x1', x1);
  line.set('y1', y1);
  line.set('x2', x2);
  line.set('y2', y2);

  const angle = calcAngle(x1 - x2, y2 - y1);

  triangle.set('angle', angle);
  triangle.setCoords();

  c.renderAll();
}

const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: 'black',
  radius: 20,
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false
});

const triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  fill: 'orange',
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  top: 50,
  left: 120,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

const coords = [
  triangle.left,
  triangle.top,
  circle.left + circle.radius,
  circle.top + circle.radius
];

const line = new fabric.Line(coords, {
  stroke: 'orange',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  selectable: false
});

c.add(circle, line, triangle);

c.on('object:moving', syncObjects);
```